# validate radio button onClick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

Need to do validation on radio buttons onClick function.

HTML CODE :

```
<fieldset>

    <div class="t box"><h4>T</h4>

    <div class="radio-buttons-1">

     <label class="radio-inline">

<input type="radio" name="tw" value="tw15"> 15

     </label>

 <label class="radio-inline">

<input type="radio" name="tw" value="tw16"> 16

</label>

</div>

<br>

<span class="error-messages-tw" style="display:none; color:#F44336; font-size:16px; font-weight:700;">

</span>

<br><br>

<div class="tw15 box2">

<select name="twg" class="form-control is_twg" onChange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">


<option value="" >Select One</option>

<option value="twy">Yes</option><option value="twn">No</option>

</select>

<br>

<span class="error-messages-twg" style="display:none; color:#F44336; font-size:16px; font-weight:700;">

</span>

<br><br>

<div id="div8" class="showMe"><br>

<h4>Select One Option </h4>

<div class="radio-buttons-1">

<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="twga" value="a" > a

</label>

<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="twga" value="b" > b

</label>

<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="twga" value="c" > c

</label>

<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="twga" value="d"> d

</label>

</div>

<br>

<span class="error-messages-twga" style="display:none; color:#F44336; font-size:16px; font-weight:700;">

</span>

<br><br>

</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-next1">Next 

<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>

</button>

</fieldset>
```

JS Code :

```
 $('.msf-form .btn-next1').on('click', function() {  

    var parent_fieldset = $(this).parents('fieldset');

    var next_step = true;       


if(parent_fieldset.find("input[type='radio']").length > 0){

       if (!$('input[name="twga"]:visible:checked').val()) {

         $(".error-messages-twga").text("Please Select option").fadeIn();

         next_step = false;

       } 

else {

         $(".error-messages-twga").empty().fadeOut();

       }

      }


 parent_fieldset.find('.is_twg:visible').each(function() {  

    if( $(this).val() == "" ) {

    $(this).focus().css('border','1px solid #F44336');

    $(".error-messages-twg").text("Please Select One Option").fadeIn();

    next_step = false;

            }

    else{

    $(this).focus().css('border','0px solid #F44336');

    $(".error-messages-twg").empty().fadeOut();


        }
        });       
      });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the problem? Tell us what goes wrong when you run your code.

Answer (score 1):

first of all your javascript code has missing brackets..

Replace your JS Code with this

```
$('.msf-form .btn-next').on('click', function() {  

    var parent_fieldset = $(this).parents('fieldset');
    var next_step = true;


        parent_fieldset.find('.is_abc').each(function() {                              
            if( $(this).val() == "" ) {

                $(".error-messages-abc").text("Please Select option").fadeIn();
                next_step = false;
            }
            else{

           $(".error-messages-abc").empty().fadeOut();
            }
        });
});
```

Now check again if its working.

Comment: no it is same as it was earlier. It validate the radio button. But validation stick on that when radio button is selected.

Comment: you need to show your full html because i dont see any `.error-messages-abc` class and `.btn-next` class in the HTML you have provided

Answer (score 0):

Change your js code to,

```
$('.msf-form .btn-next').on('click', function() {
  var parent_fieldset = $(this).parents('fieldset');
  var next_step = true;
  if (!$('input[name="abc"]:checked').val()) {
    $(".error-messages-abc").text("Please Select option").fadeIn();
    next_step = false;
  } else {
    $(".error-messages-abc").empty().fadeOut();
  }
});
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

**EDIT** :

```
$('.msf-form .btn-next').on('click', function() {
      var parent_fieldset = $(this).parents('fieldset');
      var next_step = true;
      if(parent_fieldset.find("input[type='radio']").length > 0){
       if (!$('input[name="abc"]:checked').val()) {
         $(".error-messages-abc").text("Please Select option").fadeIn();
         next_step = false;
       } else {
         $(".error-messages-abc").empty().fadeOut();
       }
      }
    });
```

Here, I am not sure, but **parent_fieldset** is your parent element, and inside that you want to check if radio buttons exist or not, so I kept condition considering the same.

Comment: can u pl also suggest if i have to validate only visible radio buttons what have to add in the code?

Comment: if (!$('input[name="abc"]:visible:checked').val()) { change this line like this

Comment: Its not working still validating if its not visible. Pl advise. Thanks

Comment: Please find this jsfiddle, to clear your actual problem https://jsfiddle.net/a3p2gb7p/6/ . I hide 4th radio button which is checked and validation is working fine

Comment: I am facing some other problem.  In select box when certain value is selected it opens radio button and in some select box there are no radio button, when i select option which contain no radio it still validating the radio button which are in other select options.

Comment: Mate, this is seriously, really need html code to check whats going on actually. Can you update your question with proper html, so that I can work around with that ?

Comment: Mate, where is button, where is fieldset where is form ? OK, Let me edit my answer it may work.

Comment: No its not working, the code which i have updated in that when no is selected it shows no radio button and when yes is selected there are four radio buttons and when i select No option it still validating the radio button which will show in Yes option. Pl advise.Thanks

Comment: do one thing, create jsfiddle with your complete relevant html code, as I mentioned earlier lots of things you missed to expose your html code. I will give you working code.

Comment: I have updated the code in question. In this code select box which is not visible code is not validating and its fine. But problem in radio button validation when radio button is not visible its still validating. In first radio button when 15 is selected it opens select box and in select box when yes is selected it open radio buttons and i do not want to validate these radio buttons when No option  is selected .Need Help. Pl suggest. Thanks